# Updating UI from another thread with VB in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to use a timer to scan my Xbox 360 controller. But I cannot directly update my UI like the code I wrote below.

I would get a exception when I try to run this code.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

XButton is a radiobutton on the GUI that I want to toggle.

```
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Public Class XboxControllerStatus
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed

    Dim currentState As GamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One)
    If currentState.IsConnected Then
        If currentState.Buttons.X.Pressed Then
            XButton.IsChecked = True

        Else
            XButton.IsChecked = False

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set up a delegate

> ```
> Delegate Sub SetCheckBoxCallback(ByVal value As Boolean)
> Friend Sub SetCheckBox(ByVal value As Boolean)
>     XButton.IsChecked = value
> End Sub
> ```

after that all you need to do is call the following code from within your timer to invoke it:

> Dim DesiredValue as Boolean = True
>
> Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(New SetCheckboxCallback(AddressOf SetCheckbox), New
>   Object() {DesiredValue})

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, all the time

```
Control.Invoke(sub()
                  'Put code here
               End Sub)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer - not sure why it's buried with no upvotes